# 三項演算子の中身が長くなってしまうが、規則性があるときに省略する方法

Tags: swift

以下のような条件分岐は三項演算子に置き換えると、きれいになりそうですが、結局読みにくくなってしまいます。

このようなパターンの際に、より短くきれいに書く方法はありますか？

```swift
if widthScale < heightScale {
    scale = view.image1.size.width / view.image2.size.width
} else {
    scale = view.image1.size.height / view.image2.size.height
}
```

```swift
scale = widthScale < heightScale ? view.image1.size.width / view.image2.size.width : view.image1.size.height / view.image2.size.height
```

Comment: いったん、文字数の短い変数に代入して、それを三項演算子で判断するぐらいしか方法はないかと思います。

Comment: プロパティを何段階も辿っているで短縮しようが無いと思いますが、例えば、CGSizeにextensionでアスペクト比を求める関数を持たせるとかはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: Extension以上のきれいさはさすがにできないですかね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensionか、変数に入れてきれいにするなどの方法があるようです。